# Why is it not properly sorting when its string and int but when its int and int its just fine

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df.sort_values(['Name', 'HP'], ascending=[0,1])
```

Expected

```
Name: Descending
HP: Ascending
```

ActualResult

```
Name: Descending
HP: Randomize
```

its not sorting properly when the sort is applied to a string and integer. But if its int & int it works.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your dataframe.

Comment: I tried `df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Barry', 'Joe', 'Barry'], 'HP': [1, 2, 3]})` and it worked.